# Joining data from 2 tables with has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to join data from 2 models, but it seems harder than it should be.Models:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :times

  scope :current, ->(time) do
    includes(:times).joins(:times).where("start_time < ?", time)
  end

end

class Time < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contents
end
```

Now, when I call `@content.current(Time.new)` correct SQL is generated and `AssociationRelation` is returned and  inside I can find `Content` objects.This is fine, but the problem is that I also want to access data from the Time model that is associated with `@content` and conforms to the criteria(`where("start_time < ?", time)`)
My question is, if I access `@content.current(Time.new).first.times` will I get all `Time`'s objects or only those generated from the join ? And if no, what is the best way to get data from both models ?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommand you to change the name of your Time model:

- Time is already a [class in Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Time.html)
- the function Fixnum#times returns an enumerator, which could interfer sometime

Maybe you can rename the model to `Occurence` ?

---

> "if I access Content.current(Time.new).first.times will I get all
>   Time's objects or only those generated from the join ?"

Yes, you will access to only the Time objects related to this Content object.

---

I suggest you a little improvement of your code:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :occurences

  scope :before, ->(time = Time.current) do
    includes(:occurences).where("occurences.start_time < ?", time)
  end

end

class Occurence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :content
end

# usage:
Content.before.first.times # default value for .before() scope is Time.current
Content.before(Time.current - 1.years)

@content = Content.before.first
@occurences_of_this_content = @content.occurences
```

Comment: Time is not really my model name, im just using it here.Thank you for your code, but I still don't know how to get Content along with Occurences...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that I couldn't get all Occurences, I could.In my  first message I wrote @content.current(Time.new).first.times. Instead, I want Occurences that are result of the join of Content and Occurences tables with the criteria where("occurences.start_time < ?", time).In English, give me all Content objects and their associated Occurences where occurences.start_time < time